# Hazelcast forcefully call loadAll() method when any of the Hazelcast member goes down

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have implemented read-through using `MapLoader` with `loadAll` key functionality which loads specific list of keys and value from database to Hazelcast map during map initialization. My question is if some of the member goes down, I need repopulate those keys and values accordingly. This is because we are aggressively using Hazelcast predicates to search the relevant data (not by the key) but if one the member goes down there are chances we won't be getting actual result from cache.

As far as I know Hazelcast will also not create any backup of data which are configured with `MapLoader`. Only one option I can think of is to forcefully call `loadAll` function of `MapLoader` once any of the members goes down. But not really sure how to implement the same. I am also open for other suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know Hazelcast will also not create any backup of data which are configured with MapLoader.

I am not sure what made you believe that. Backups and MapLoader are two separate configuration settings on a map and you can configure them independently. So unless you configured zero backups you will have a backup of your data, even when loaded by a `MapLoader`.

For more see [Making Your Map Data Safe](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/data-structures/backing-up-maps) section in the documentation.

If you want to **reload** the data using MapLoader you can use `com.hazelcast.map.IMap#loadAll(boolean)` for all data or `com.hazelcast.map.IMap#loadAll(java.util.Set<K>, boolean)` for specific set of keys.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.  Actually, I was little confused with below statement written in hazelcast doc :-
 "note that the IMap.get() method does not create backup copies for such entries, when the mode is read-through persistence: there is no need for backups for these entries since if the primary entry is lost, then a read for the key triggers the load() method and loads the entry from the persistence layer." source https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map.

Comment: But I guess my confusion is clear now, this is only applicable for Imap.get call but if I am loading the data using loadAll (maploader), hazelcast will create the backup based on configured backup count. please correct me if I am wrong.